# SBT project Depedencies

Tags: dependencies, sbt, slf4j-api

I have a sbt project. It has many dependencies defined in the build.sbt file.
So recently when i start my application i am seeing that it is automatically downloading the latest alpha version of slf4j-api which is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.8.0-alpha1.

So after this gets updated my logging is breaking. I cant figure out which exact dependency is downloading the latest version of slf4j-api so that i can exclude it.

Comment: Got a similar problem, except with Gradle